# How to use naturalspeech2-pytorch convert text to audio

Tags: python, django, audio, text, python-module

I'm developing the audio service with whisper, Ghat_GPT and naturalspeech2-pytorch.
What I need to solve is to implement the naturalspeech2-pytorch python module to convert the text to audio.
I'm lacked the data.
Which python version Do I need to do.
please help me.

I tried naturalspeech2-pytorch to convert text to audio.

Comment: Please ensure to provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example